# Unresolved reference 'folder' problem with my project

Tags: python, import, pycharm

Currently I have: `project/inside_project/file.py` and `project/__init__.py`

Inside `file.py` I am trying to import my database from inside `__init__.py` using

```
from project import db
```

I get the error `Unresolved reference 'folder'`. PyCharm's solution is `Install package folder`, which is not what I need, of course.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not doing any wrong. Just right-click the main project directory and go to  'Make Directory as' and then click on the 'Sources Root'. This should solve your problem.

Comment: On which folder you have right-clicked. Is it *project* folder or the *inside_project* folder. @zfac122

Comment: *project* is the one I clicked